# Making images repaint faster

Tags: java, graphics, keyboard, repaint, thread-sleep

I have a working code where you can control the movement of a goldfish with the arrow keypad. When you press the up key, the goldfish swim up. When you press the down key, the goldfish swim down. When you press the left key, the goldfish swim left. And when you press the right key, the goldfish swim right. I made it so that the goldfish's pixel increase or decrease by exactly 1 pixel every time it moves in a new direction, but when you do it like that the goldfish swims very slowly. I know that if you increase the pixel by more than 1 the goldfish seems to be swimming faster, but then that way it wouldn't paint every pixel, and the goldfish swimming won't look as smooth. So my question is, is there a way to repaint the goldfish to go faster without increasing the pixels it paints by? Here's my code:

```
public class Fishy extends Panel implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener {
static int x1;// first x location of the shape.
static int x2;// second x location of the shape
static int y1;// first y location of the shape
static int y2;// second y location of the shape
static int shapeWidth;// width of the shape
static int shapeHeight;// height of the shape
static final int left = 37;
static final int right = 39;
static final int down = 40;
static final int up = 38;
static boolean leftPress;
static boolean rightPress;
static boolean upPress;
static boolean downPress;
static int speed = 1;
static int x;
static int y;
static int size = 50;
static String facingDirection = "RIGHT";
int enemyX1;
int enemyY1;
int enemyX2;
int enemyY2;
int enemySpeed;
int enemySize;

static Image LimageFishy = new ImageIcon("F://Picture//Lfish.png").getImage();
static Image RimageFishy = new ImageIcon("F://Picture//Rfish.png").getImage();
static BufferedImage bufferedImageFishy;

Fishy enemyFish[] = new Fishy[20];

static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fishy");

// TREE method of extending classes[]

static Fishy fishy = new Fishy(1000, 500, 9);

Fishy(int width, int length, int minusBy) {
    super(width, length, minusBy);
}

/* Graphics goes here */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);

    // size++;
     if (facingDirection.equals("RIGHT")) {
     g.drawImage(RimageFishy, x1, y1, size, size, null);
     }
     if (facingDirection.equals("LEFT")) {
     g.drawImage(LimageFishy, x1, y1, size, size, null);
     }

    g.drawString(DraggingShapes.mousePointerLocation, 50, 50);

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    frame.addKeyListener(fishy);
    fishy.addMouseMotionListener(fishy);

    frame.add(fishy);
    Frame.showFrame(frame, false);

    /*while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1);
        if (x1 < 1000) {
            x1++;
        } else {
            x1 = 0;
        }
        frame.repaint();
    }*/

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (up == e.getKeyCode()) {

        upPress = true;
    }
    if (down == e.getKeyCode()) {

        downPress = true;
    }
    if (left == e.getKeyCode()) {

        leftPress = true;
        facingDirection = "LEFT";
    }
    if (right == e.getKeyCode()) {

        rightPress = true;
        facingDirection = "RIGHT";
    }

    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

    if (upPress == true && leftPress == false && rightPress == false) {
        fishy.y1 -= speed;
    }
    if (downPress == true && leftPress == false && rightPress == false) {
        fishy.y1 += speed;
    }
    if (leftPress == true && upPress == false && downPress == false) {
        fishy.x1 -= speed;
    }
    if (rightPress == true && upPress == false && downPress == false) {
        fishy.x1 += speed;
    }

    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

    if (leftPress == true && upPress == true) {
        fishy.x1 -= speed;
        fishy.y1 -= speed;
    }
    if (leftPress == true && downPress == true) {
        fishy.x1 -= speed;
        fishy.y1 += speed;
    }
    if (rightPress == true && upPress == true) {
        fishy.x1 += speed;
        fishy.y1 -= speed;
    }
    if (rightPress == true && downPress == true) {
        fishy.x1 += speed;
        fishy.y1 += speed;
    }

    System.out.println("PRESSING (Left:" + leftPress + ") (Right:" + rightPress + ") (Up:" + upPress + ") (Down:" + downPress + ")");
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    if (up == e.getKeyCode()) {
        upPress = false;

    }
    if (down == e.getKeyCode()) {
        downPress = false;

    }
    if (left == e.getKeyCode()) {
        leftPress = false;

    }
    if (right == e.getKeyCode()) {
        rightPress = false;

    }

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    DraggingShapes.showPointerLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    repaint();

}

/*** METHODS THAT WE'RE NOT GOING TO USE ***/
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

}

}
```

Also, I notice that when you're not controlling the image with keyboard input, and just telling it to repaint using Thread.sleep(millisecond), when you're telling it to Thread.sleep(1 millisecond), the image repaints really fast, even if you're only increasing it by 1 pixel, and I'm wondering why it isn't the same with keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

If the key is held, the KeyListener will fire every n milliseconds (this may be OS dependent, but on my Windows system n ~ 33ms). So the repaint will be called every ~ n milliseconds. Relative to the Thread.sleep(1) method, this is ~ n times slower (note this is approximate as repaint is a request for the EDT to paint, and speed it actually works may depend upon the repaint queue and the painting itself). As a result, at 33ms your object is only traveling ~30 pixels/second.

I wouldn't necessary recommend trying to increase the rate of repainting to speed it up, rather to speed it up by increasing the rate at which it moves (eg the speed variable). Along these same lines, you can use a Swing timer to provide the animation loop.

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(60, new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        repaint();
    }

});
timer.start();
```

This gives you finer control over how fast animation occurs. You change the model with the UI listener elements (or otherwise), and rely on this timer for the animation. A descent rule of thumb might be to have the timer fire every 60ms. Note this would not speed things up - just give you finer control over the animation process.

Comment: Did you put the timer.start() in the right spot? So the 60 is standing for 60 pixels per second right? Dammit, I thought there was a different way to increase the image without increasing the pixels it repaints by. When it gets even faster, the images gets really choppy, because it updates by a lot of pixels per keylistener called. I've seen games when images moves really fast, but doesn't look choppy at all. How do they do it like that?

Comment: See the API for the Swing timer class - the first parameter to its constructor (60 in my post) defines how fast the timer will fire in milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if this is exactly what your looking for but this might be the reason why there was some discrepancy between you using sleep(1) vs using the keyboard to move the fish. I refactored your code by adding a HashMap, as it allows for much easier updating and using that to update the direction variables.

```
public class Fishy extends Panel implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener {


    // here is the map declaration for the data structure
    // that will map the key, which was an integer, to
    // (up,down,right,left)press, which was a boolean.

    static Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();


    static int x1;// first x location of the shape.
    static int x2;// second x location of the shape
    static int y1;// first y location of the shape
    static int y2;// second y location of the shape
    static int shapeWidth;// width of the shape
    static int shapeHeight;// height of the shape
    static final int left = 37;
    static final int right = 39;
    static final int down = 40;
    static final int up = 38;
    static boolean leftPress;
    static boolean rightPress;
    static boolean upPress;
    static boolean downPress;
    static int speed = 1;
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static int size = 50;
    static String facingDirection = "RIGHT";
    int enemyX1;
    int enemyY1;
    int enemyX2;
    int enemyY2;
    int enemySpeed;
    int enemySize;


    static Image LimageFishy = new ImageIcon("F://Picture//Lfish.png").getImage();
    static Image RimageFishy = new ImageIcon("F://Picture//Rfish.png").getImage();
    static BufferedImage bufferedImageFishy;

    Fishy enemyFish[] = new Fishy[20];

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fishy");

    // TREE method of extending classes[]

    static Fishy fishy = new Fishy(1000, 500, 9);

    Fishy(int width, int length, int minusBy) {
        super(width, length, minusBy);
    }

    /* Graphics goes here */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);

        // size++;
         if (facingDirection.equals("RIGHT")) {
         g.drawImage(RimageFishy, x1, y1, size, size, null);
         }
         if (facingDirection.equals("LEFT")) {
         g.drawImage(LimageFishy, x1, y1, size, size, null);
         }

        g.drawString(DraggingShapes.mousePointerLocation, 50, 50);

    }


    static void buildMap() {
        map.put(up, false);
        map.put(down, false);
        map.put(left, false);
        map.put(right, false);

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        buildMap();

        frame.addKeyListener(fishy);
        fishy.addMouseMotionListener(fishy);

        frame.add(fishy);
        Frame.showFrame(frame, false);

        /*while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            if (x1 < 1000) {
                x1++;
            } else {
                x1 = 0;
            }
            frame.repaint();
        }*/

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        // using the hashmap, we can refactor away the if statements
        map.put(e.getKeyCode(), true);

        /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

        // It is possible to refactor away the following if statements
        // but that requires further surgery on the code.

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue()) {
                if (entry.getKey() == up) {
                    fishy.y1 -= speed;
                }
                else if (entry.getKey() == down) {
                    fishy.y1 += speed;

                }
                else if (entry.getKey() == right) {
                    fishy.x1 += speed;

                }
                else if (entry.getKey() == left) {
                    fishy.x1 -= speed;

                }
            }
        }



        System.out.println("PRESSING (Left:" + leftPress + ") (Right:" + rightPress + ") (Up:" + upPress + ") (Down:" + downPress + ")");
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        // got rid of the unnecessary if statements
        // and directly accessed the hashmap to update the value
        map.put(e.getKeyCode(), false);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        DraggingShapes.showPointerLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        repaint();

    }

    /*** METHODS THAT WE'RE NOT GOING TO USE ***/
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    }
```

Comment: it was a long shot, but i thought the discrepancy might have been due to the excessive amounts of if statements in the program logic

Comment: I can't find the answer anywhere. Maybe you can't make it go any faster without increasing the pixel it goes by? I wish someone could come by and verify  that or something.

Comment: The discrepency is due to the rate at which repaint is called. The Keylistener can only fire at a certain rate, which is much slower than every single millisecond.

Comment: @copeg is there any way to make the keylistener fire faster?

Comment: AFAIK, not a direct way. A crude hack (not necessarily recommended) would be to manage a timer that would fire between the KeyListener events (either a non-repeating, or something you manually stop later).